# VSS failure due to shadow storage size

Tags: c++, windows, volume-shadow-service

I have used VSS API to make snapshot of C:. The program fails with VSS exception. But when I try to create snapshot of same volume using VSS Admin it completes successfully.

I found the shadow storage space is less then 300 mb and hence it caused my program to fail. Increasing the space of shadow storage worked for me.

My questions are:

1. How does VSS Admin work fine even if the shadowstorage space is less than 300MB?
2. Why can't a program created using VSS API also create a snapshot?

What's missing?